# Full table scan or index scan

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, query-optimization

There is a large Oracle table `A` and relatively large global temp table `TB` used by following query:

```
UPDATE  A
SET     A.field0 = ( SELECT SUM(TB.field0)
                     FROM   TB
                     WHERE  TB.field1 = A.field1 AND
                            TB.field2 = A.field2 AND
                            TB.field3 = 'value' )
WHERE   EXIST ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   TB
                 WHERE  TB.field1 = A.field1 AND
                        TB.field2 = A.field2 AND
                        TB.field3 = 'value' );
```

Basically the `EXIST` condition is used just to check if a record ever existed. Now for this query, if there is index on `A.field0` and `A.field1`, but no index on `TB` at all, is it going to do a full table scan or index scan? Furthermore, is the `WHERE` condition necessary and any performance impact from it?

Comment: There's too many factors that run into determining an execution plan for a query. We don't know indexes, number of records, clustering, etc. Talk to your DBA or evaluate the execution plan yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no indexes on `TB` the `SELECT` sub-queries in the SQL will go for a full table scan on TB. If TB table is large creating indexes on `TB.field1`,`TB.field2`,`TB.field3` should give significant performance improvement.

Comment: Correct, with no index on TB, full table scan is required.

Comment: @Arun thanks, any potential concern on placing indexes on global temp table?

Comment: I think it should be fine but I am not an expert so I may be wrong. Here is a link that discusses this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941094/is-it-safe-to-put-an-index-on-an-oracle-temporary-table. Maybe @unleashed can give some inputs

Comment: @Dreamer  No concerns I know of relating to indexes on GTT's.